# I created an unmanaged package in a Developer org, but I can't figure out how to install it into a sandbox

Tags: sandbox, unmanaged-package, package-install, developer-org

I developed a custom app in my developer org and I want to deploy it to sandbox via unmanaged package .

I created an unmanaged package in a Developer org, but I can't figure out how to install it into a sandbox

Answer (score 4):

Once you get the unmanaged package link ,you will replace login with test

Lets say your unmanaged package link is

https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t28000000B4ng

Your package link for sandbox is as below

https://test.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t28000000B4ng

Edit

Also note it takes significant amount of time for package to appear .Wait for atleast 30 minutes before pressing panic button

Comment: Yes, I did the same still getting the error "This app can't be installed.
There are problems that prevent this package from being installed.
Package Not Found The requested package does not exist or has been deleted. Please contact the package publisher for assistance. If this is a recently uploaded package, please try again soon."

Comment: Nayana ,It will take some time .I edited answer to add time you should least wait

Comment: @nayanapawar The package has to be "replicated" across instances. I have seen this take upwards of a few hours, although they usually recommend at least 30 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for reply Mohith... Almost 45 mins before I have created a package. May I know how much time it will take?

Comment: If problem persists , repackage it .If still don't work raise a case with support